# If variable is set, then ECHO

Tags: php

I know there is

```
if (isset($string))
{
    echo $string;
}
```

but is there a way to do this with a statement? I found one thing that looks like it might be it but I was wrong. It was

```
var_dump(isset($string));
```

So im looking for something that does all of the if variable is set, then echo the variable all in one statement..

Comment: your definition of statement, is not the same a mine. A function perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
echo (isset($string)) ? $string : null;
```

That is called a [Ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) Operator.

Not sure I fully understand the question.